How to set counter value in TIM5 in Stm32 before starting it?
I am currently using Stm32F446Ret6 board for a project which involves starting timer, for which i am using Tim5. The problem i am facing is __HAL_TIM_SET_COUNTER(&htim5, 2000); is not setting the counter value of tim5 to 2000.
__HAL_TIM_SET_AUTORELOAD(&htim5, 36000000*processLimit[6]);
__HAL_TIM_SET_COUNTER(&htim5, 2000);
HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim5);

autoreload and interrupt functions are working perfectly fine but counter set function is giving me problems
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim);

the above function also works fine,
what might be the problem?

__HAL_TIM_SET_COUNTER(&htim5, 2000); is not setting the counter value of tim5 to 2000  How do you know?

Try to debug your code and make sure set counter is not ok
you can add    TIM5->CNT     to debug watch window and see the resault.

Thank you, I made a mistake to display the counter value as int, i think thats why it showed 0 when starting the timer, as counter value i set is 2000

uint32_t counter_value = __HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim5);
ElapsedTime = (int)counter_value/10000;
sprintf(command, "SElapsedTime.val=%d", ElapsedTime);
SendToNextion(command);

I made a mistake to display the counter value as int, I think thats why it showed 0 when starting the timer, as counter value I set is 2000. I watched the timer's couter value from the nextion HMI display connected via UART, thats how I debugged the issue.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
